# Skrill how to test postback to my server?

Tags: c#, asp.net, payment-gateway

I am integrating Skrill to my website. Skrill requires you to insert thank you page URL and postback url in settings.

I would like to know if there is an option to make test payments with skrill (their support is useless and takes forever to reply anything).

So for example after payment is successful it redirects you to thank you page, but I want to know what happens in background when Skrill sends request to my URL which actually updates data in my database.

If I want to test it now, I have to make real payments which is stupid, because I just want to test until everything works.

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

They do have the ability to test, though you will need to get test details (username etc.) from Skrill and this will be different depending on your type of integration.

https://www.moneybookers.com/merchant/en/moneybookers_gateway_manual.pdf